# MySQL Authentication Error After Re-applying the mysqldump after an upgrade

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, authentication

After upgrading from a lower version of MySQL 5.5.* to MySQL 5.5.52, after reapplying the mysqldump that I took before the upgrade, I am receiving the following error:

```
Authentication to host 'localhost' for user '[user]' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user '[user]'@'localhost' (using password: YES) ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user '[user]'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to run the `mysql_upgrade` command after re-applying the mysqldump after the update.

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p --force
```